# Is there a way to pass --compressed into PHP's curl_setopt()?

Tags: php, curl

When using curl, I'm seeing a difference in behaviors on the server I'm hitting depending on if I passed `--compressed` as an argument or not.

I'm already setting the Accept-Encoding header to gzip,deflate,sdch:

```
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate,sdch' );
```

I've also tried setting the encoding to empty string: '' since that supposedly means any type compression is supported.

However, if I've pass `--compressed` via the command line, the content type I get back is: `gzip`. If I don't pass in `--compressed`, the content type I get back is `text/html;charset=UTF-8`

Using PHP's `curl_exec()`, I can't ever seem to get it to return a content-type: gzip.

=====

Let me clarify what I'm trying to accomplish. When I run the following command: `curl -I http://someserver.com --compressed` gets me content-type: `gzip`

Running the same command `curl -I http://someserver.com` without `--compressed` gets me 
content-type: `text/html;charset=UTF-8`

Trying to do this in PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://someserver.com" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

// I've tried excluding this line, setting it to gzip, and empty string
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' ); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

curl_exec( $ch ) );
$content_type = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE );
```

No matter what I try, I'm getting $content-type = `text/html;charset=UTF-8` and not `gzip`

Comment: The `Content-Type` header is absolutely fine. It looks to me as through you are actually interested in the `Content-Encoding` header (for `Content-Encoding: gzip`).

Answer (score 2):

Not all serves around the world provide the compressed content as a response. Through the option `CURLOPT_ENCODING` you can only ask for compressed content from the server. But server will return you plain html if it has not implemented the mechanism. You can try with other random websites which provides compress content. For example youtube.com(probably).

Comment: I'm actually testing this against the same server, not just any server. I apologize if my somerandomserver.com caused any confusion.

Comment: i understand... But still try the same code for any other site and check whether they return the desired output or not... If yes, the its the issue with your server, not with curl...

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `CURLOPT_ENCODING` option (so curl doesn't auto-decode) and putting the `accept-encoding` option in the header manually should do the trick :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'Connection: Close'
));
```

Comment: I've tried empty string as the encoding (as mentioned in my original post), but curl_getinfo still shows `text/html;charset=UTF-8` as the content type.

Comment: Curl decompresses the response automatically.

Comment: Yes, I've figured that part out after scouring their documentation, but by leaving out CURLOPT_ENCODING, you're also telling the server to no compress the response.

I've found this and was able to see the compressed response, but that's not my goal: http://trog.qgl.org/20110729/differences-in-requesting-gziped-content-using-curl-in-php

Comment: Have you considered using a system call so you won't use the wrapper but curl itself?

Comment: Was going to try that next, since I know running the curl command works, but wanted to see if it was possible to do it via PHP.

Comment: You might then be able to do that using CURLOPT_HEADER and setting Accept-Encoding contents to what you need.