# cURL response not readable

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem with my cURL response, when I try to invoke the method of WSDL, I receive this weird text from my browser,

```
�d�ْ�<�_��[�7�4eS�@���8 �]��Q��A���>�t�,����]�1��%Y���4!l�^ZG��,8��v��������#ZJ�W��
r)0Ek����Q�����"Ᏹ�!�0��0����(�T�$���� Z��փ��UU���g������&�C�f
8�!��5��L�t{����6�?{jY�Q��?���K����3�D2�e   �߱Oc����@^P��$�IΠ�4A[;�p�\7�����i5��+�\歖~=����)�����a�L�GJey�F����Ɍ��v]��<��z������N����\z��.�i:�S5��FgkM�hS���|,\�0�E9i=�+ӄ�!^WҶ�7�����0�w���+b�۹��[�;���fE4_ڑ�������u�Q)E��;�;�JL���������Ԩ�1��7[�$D���\�W���ۂU$9���
```

How can I solve this?

Here's my header

```
$headers = array(
                "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
                "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=\"UTF-8\"",
                "SOAPAction: \"http://tempuri.org/"",
                "Host: domain.com",
                "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
                "Connection: Keep-Alive"
                );
```

and here's my curl options

```
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        120);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,    true); // new
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,      10);   // new
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // new
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );            
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $xml_post_string); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,        TRUE); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $headers);
```

Comment: Is the response tarred or zipped by any chance?

Comment: its weird because, yesterday, I just started this code, and I receive a readable text just like, the exact error: "refNo not found" but now, I didn't understand what happen. The respone should be text and human readable only.

Comment: You are explicitly _asking_ for a compressed version of the content (if available) with `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364640/how-to-properly-handle-a-gzipped-page-when-using-curl -- probably have to set an option..

Comment: OMG! what do I need to do to make it human readable?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145830/is-there-a-way-to-pass-compressed-into-phps-curl-setopt

Comment: Try just removing the `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` header

Answer (score 14):

Thank you guys for your comment, I have solve the issue now, shout out to Grokify, I just remove the `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` and it is now readable.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. Adding **working headers** (As of my browser) solved it for me.

**Current working code of mine:**

```
$headers = array("User-Agent: ********User Agent********");
$ch = curl_init("******URL*******");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$data= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: You've changed a **lot** of headers compared to the ones in the question without justifying the individual changes. The answer from half a decade ago makes the minimal change needed to solve the problem.

Comment: Dear @Quentin, I was getting unreadable output from CURL and Adding UserAgent fixed it. Thus I posted it so others reaching this post try this as well, though, you are right this is not a direct answer to the specific scenario in question.